# Как включить виртуализацию на виртуальной машине Linux

Tags: linux, виртуальная-машина, виртуализация, kvm, altlinux

Поставил на VMWare Workstation виртуальную машину с ОС ***Alt Server Virtualization v 9.2***.  На машине уже предустановлена виртуализация от `libvirt`. При попытке создать внутри этой ВМ новую вм через `virt-install` (осуществляю вложенную виртуализацию) получаю ошибку: `host does not support domain type kvm for virtualization type hvm with architecture x86_64`

Использовал команду `lsmod | grep kvm`, ничего не вывелось. Узнал, что это связано с тем, что  модули ядра для виртуализации KVM не загружены в системе. Начал гуглить и нашел способ через команду `modprobe`. Прописал `modprobe kvm-install`, получил такую ошибку: `modprobe: error: could not insert 'kvm_intel': operation not permitted`. Делал все под рутом. Последнее, что я сделал, это использовал команду `dmesg | grep kvm` и получил такое сообщение: `kvm: no hardware support`.
Собственно вопрос: есть ли вообще возможность как-то аппаратно включить виртуализацию на такой виртуальной машине, если да, то как? Буду очень признателен за ответ.

[image: Создание виртуальной машины]

Comment: В VMware поищи галочку nested virtualization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настройках VMware esxi Галка называется  "Expose hardware-assisted virtualization to the guest operating system." , в workstation - "Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI."

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Nested-Virtualization-Documents/Running-Nested-VMs/ta-p/2781466

Comment: Искал проблему в линуксе, а она была на поверхности. Спасибо, после вашего ответа всё заработало.